# ActiveRecord Nested Arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Do any methods / patterns exist for sanitizing an array of arrays when using it as SQL input?

Looking to implement the following style of query in ActiveRecord:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "addresses"
WHERE ("addresses"."city", "addresses"."state", "addresses"."country") IN (
  ('Juneau', 'AK', 'US'), 
  ('Albany', 'NY', 'US'),
  ...
)
```

For example:

```rb
searches = [
  ['Juneau', 'AK', 'US'],
  ['Albany', 'NY', 'US'],
]

searches_sql = searches.map do |search| 
  "(#{search.map { |query| Address.connection.quote(query) }.join(', ')})"
end.join(', ')
Address.where(%(("addresses"."city", "addresses"."state", "addresses"."country") IN (#{searches_sql})))
```

Works but relies on some manual connection escaping that doesn't seem ideal (and isn't easily generalized beyond this scope).

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord does not actually have a built in way to construct a `WHERE columns IN values` query.

But you can do it with Arel:

```
class Address
  def self.search(sets)
    where(
      Arel::Nodes::In.new(
        [:city, :state, :country].map { |c| arel_table[c] },
        sets.map do |set|
          Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new(
            set.map {|value| Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(value)}
          )
        end
      )
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: This is interesting - thanks!, I'm not sure about the statement that ActiveRecord does not have a way to build `WHERE IN` queries. For example `Address.where(city: %w[Juneau Albany])` generates a IN query `SELECT  "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."city" IN ('Juneau', 'Albany')`. Also appears to have some formatting issues around brackets (i.e. doesn't treat the city / state / country as a tuple).

Comment: Yea but AR will only create a query for a single column, not to match a list of columns to sets of values like the query you are trying to create.